# Class with same name as the engine doesn't work in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines, class-method, ruby-on-rails-5.1

In my Rails engine I'd like to have a class with the engine name.

Copying Rails way to create a class from Rails engine (see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails.rb#L34-L113)) I created a class which is named along the engine name.

Now, running `Myengine.foo` in a initializer correctly returns `foo`, but if I try on rails console I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'foo' for Myengine:Module`.

See the code below:

```
require "myengine/engine"

module Myengine
  class << self
    def foo
        puts 'foo'
    end
  end
end
```

Don't know if it's important, but I'm obviously trying to call `Myengine.foo` from the console of the application on which the engine is mounted.

Comment: what's `Myengine.constants` output

Comment: `Myengine.constants` output `[:VERSION, :Engine, :ApplicationRecord, :User]`

Comment: `User` must be due to Devise.

Comment: So your issue is that the initialiser isn't being loaded? Where is it located?

Comment: I'm not sure the problem is the initializer, infact I can do `Myengine.foo` in any application controller and returns `foo`. My guess is that the application console cannot call `Myengine` as class, because it first get the module. A sort of name collision.

Comment: One important thing: my initializer is in `myengine/config/initializers/myengine.rb`. But the class and the methods are created in `myengine/lib/myengine.rb`.

Comment: @Tom Lord. Why did you ask me what were `Myengine.constants`? If there is a **proper** way to do it which is different from my setup please let me know. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: @TomLord I moved helper methods to the `Myengine::DefaultHelpers` concern located in `Myengine/app/models/concerns/Myengine/default_helpers.rb`. On my initializer I just kept `Myengine.include Myengine::DefaultHelpers` which loads helpers when booting the application. The app console still doesn't do that by default, but it possible to load them manually running the same include command from console.